# Определить товары, которые еще никто не покупал SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть 3 следующие таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE buyers
(
    buyer_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    buyer_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    birthday DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    buyer_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES buyers (buyer_id),
    order_number INT NOT NULL, 
    order_date DATE NOT NULL,
    order_summa MONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE products
(
    product_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(200),
    price MONEY NOT NULL,
    type_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES product_types (type_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders_products
(
    order_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES orders (order_id),
    product_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES products (product_id)
);
```

Необходимо написать запрос, который выведет наименование и цену товаров, которые ещё никто не покупал (должен быть 1 товар). Нужно использовать в запросе NULL. Пишу такой запрос, но ничего не выводит:

```
SELECT product_name, price
FROM orders
JOIN orders_products ON orders.order_id = orders_products.order_id
JOIN products ON orders_products.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN buyers ON orders.buyer_id = buyers.buyer_id
WHERE products.product_id IS NULL;
```

Если написать IS NOT NULL, то выводятся все записи, кроме той, которой должна быть при IS NULL.

Comment: *Необходимо написать запрос, который выведет наименование и цену товаров, которые ещё никто не покупал (должен быть 1 товар).* Первые две таблицы для этого запроса не нужны в принципе. Задача решается элементарно путём использования WHERE NOT EXISTS. *Нужно использовать в запросе NULL.* Ооо! так это домашнее задание, оказывается? ну тогда LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL.

Comment: @Akina С LEFT тоже ничего не выводится.

Comment: @Akina Вот так написал: SELECT product_name, price
FROM products
LEFT JOIN orders_products ON products.product_id = orders_products.product_id
WHERE products.product_id IS NULL;

Comment: @EgaNator, почти правильно, только WHERE orders_products.product_id IS NULL

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Спасибо большое! Понял теперь, как нужно было писать запрос.